# What would the correct syntax be for this REGEX expression?

Tags: .net, regex, firefox

I have the following REGEX code, ie:

> `/^IT [0-9]{1,5}/(?<y1>19)?(?(y1)\d{2}|20\d{2})\((?<n1>M)?(?(n1)N|[H|B|C|D|E|G|K|M|U|N|L|S|T|V])\)$/`

It is meant to check a group of words and ensure that it evaluates to:

> `IT 1/2014(G)`

or any value up to 5 digits

> `IT 5000/2014(MN)`

I keep getting the following error when running the above in firefox however:

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid regexp group`

Any help at all wouild be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern contains an if clause which is not supported.

```
(?<y1>19)?(?(y1)\d{2}|20\d{2})
```

If group `y1` exists, match 19 and 2 digits, else match 20 and 2 digits.

That can be written as `(?:19|20)\d{2}`

The same goes for

```
(?<n1>M)?(?(n1)N|[H|B|C|D|E|G|K|M|U|N|L|S|T|V])
```

If group `n1` exists, match `MN` else match one of the listed in the character class.

That can be written as `(?:MN|[HB-EGKMUNLSTV])`

---

The whole pattern might look like:

```
 ^IT [0-9]{1,5}\/(?:19|20)\d{2}\((?:MN|[HB-EGKMUNLSTV])\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uXD5ng/1)